# Send Notification in Arabic Language using GCM

Tags: android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM to send notification to android devices.

The code that I am using to get the message in GCMIntentService is as below:

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String j =intent.getStringExtra("message");
        generateNotification(ctx, j);
    }
```

And the code that I am using in server side to push or send those notification is as below:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send")
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
request.Headers.Add("Authorization: key=AIzaSyA47-XMaePL1mmI0P1yQ9V4sntMVn9q-1o")
request.Headers.Add("Sender: id=648406549877")
Dim collapsKey = Guid.NewGuid.ToString("n")
Dim postdata As String = "registration_id=" + regid_String_reveived_from_device_after_registering_with_GCM + "&data.message=" + TextBox1.Text + "&collapse_key=" + collapsKey
Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata)
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
dataStream.Close()
Dim resposne As WebResponse = request.GetResponse
Dim dataresponse As Stream = resposne.GetResponseStream
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataresponse)
Dim sResponseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd
Label2.Text = sResponseFromServer
reader.Close()
dataresponse.Close()
resposne.Close
```

When I sent any notification in English Language using the above code I received it in my device with no problem at all, But When I sent notification in Arabic language using the above code I got nothing as message which appear to me as blank in both Logcat and notification. The android API that I am using to develop this app is 16.

So how can I get the message that written in Arabic as notification, the same way that I get those messages when sent by English.

Is the problem from ASP.Net Side or android Side.

Any help or redirection will be completely appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the above problem which I was facing for one week by doing the following:

the message that I sent from the ASP.net side which is represented as `TextBox1.Text` placed in the request's body and it needs to be URL Encoded, since that I just encoded the `TextBox1.Text` value  which solve my problem and let my android app received notification in arabic languge:

I only changed my asp.net code from this:

```
Dim postdata As String = "registration_id=" + regid(i) + "&data.message=" + TextBox1.Text + "&collapse_key=" + collapsKey
```

To be Like the following:

```
Dim postdata As String = "registration_id=" + regid(i) + "&data.message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text) + "&collapse_key=" + collapsKey
```

and keep my android code as its.

Comment: @Husam, 
Can i send push notification from FCM in any other language?
I want to send a notification in my local language.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem appears to be that your requests aren't properly encoded. Google [has an article in their Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/#BuildingURLs) outlining how URLs should be built. In short, requests should be UTF-8 encoded (although spaces may be `+`).

A snippet:

> All characters to be URL-encoded are encoded using a `%` character and a two-character hex value corresponding to their UTF-8 character. For example, 上海+中國 in UTF-8 would be URL-encoded as `%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7%2B%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B`. The string `? and the Mysterians` would be URL-encoded as `%3F+and+the+Mysterians`.

The article points to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding), where details about percent-encoding can be found.

The [GCM architectural overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#request) doesn't mention any of the above, but it does specifically outline:

> The HTTP header must contain the following headers:
>
> - `Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY`
> - `Content-Type: application/json` for JSON; `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` for plain text.

You may want to consider changing your `Content-Type` header to specify `charset=UTF-8` and encode your request accordingly. Alternatively, you could try leaving your requests unencoded and experimenting with other charsets, such as [ISO-8859-6](http://www.charset.org/charactersets.php?charset=iso-8859-6).